# Can I switch to using Openzeppelin Defender or other relayer service from Biconomy with same contract deployed? How to do it?

Tags: meta-transactions, relay

I have deployed the following contract using the BasicMetatransaction.sol file. Attaching the code for that too.

I am using Biconomy for relaying gasless transactions. Can I switch to Openzeppelin Defender or any other relayer service later on?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.8.18;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./BasicMetaTransaction.sol";

contract FunToken is BasicMetaTransaction, ERC20, Ownable {
constructor(
    string memory name,
    string memory symbol,
    uint256 initialSupply
) ERC20(name, symbol) {
    _mint(_msgSender(), initialSupply * 10 ** decimals());
}

function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(to, amount);
}

function decimals() public pure override returns (uint8) {
    return 6;
}

function _msgSender()
    internal
    view
    override(Context, BasicMetaTransaction)
    returns (address sender)
{
    if (msg.sender == address(this)) {
        bytes memory array = msg.data;
        uint256 index = msg.data.length;
        assembly {
            // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
            sender := and(
                mload(add(array, index)),
                0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
            )
        }
    } else {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

}

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

 contract BasicMetaTransaction {
 using SafeMath for uint256;

 event MetaTransactionExecuted(
    address userAddress,
    address payable relayerAddress,
    bytes functionSignature
);
mapping(address => uint256) private nonces;

function getChainID() public view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 id;
    assembly {
        id := chainid()
    }
    return id;
}

/**
 * Main function to be called when user wants to execute meta transaction.
 * The actual function to be called should be passed as param with name functionSignature
 * Here the basic signature recovery is being used. Signature is expected to be generated using
 * personal_sign method.
 * @param userAddress Address of user trying to do meta transaction
 * @param functionSignature Signature of the actual function to be called via meta transaction
 * @param sigR R part of the signature
 * @param sigS S part of the signature
 * @param sigV V part of the signature
 */
function executeMetaTransaction(
    address userAddress,
    bytes memory functionSignature,
    bytes32 sigR,
    bytes32 sigS,
    uint8 sigV
) public payable returns (bytes memory) {
    require(
        verify(
            userAddress,
            nonces[userAddress],
            getChainID(),
            functionSignature,
            sigR,
            sigS,
            sigV
        ),
        "Signer and signature do not match"
    );
    nonces[userAddress] = nonces[userAddress].add(1);

    // Append userAddress at the end to extract it from calling context
    (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
        abi.encodePacked(functionSignature, userAddress)
    );

    require(success, "Function call not successful");
    emit MetaTransactionExecuted(
        userAddress,
        payable(msg.sender),
        functionSignature
    );
    return returnData;
}

function getNonce(address user) external view returns (uint256 nonce) {
    nonce = nonces[user];
}

// Builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
    return
        keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash)
        );
}

function verify(
    address owner,
    uint256 nonce,
    uint256 chainID,
    bytes memory functionSignature,
    bytes32 sigR,
    bytes32 sigS,
    uint8 sigV
) public view returns (bool) {
    bytes32 hash = prefixed(
        keccak256(abi.encodePacked(nonce, this, chainID, functionSignature))
    );
    address signer = ecrecover(hash, sigV, sigR, sigS);
    require(signer != address(0), "Invalid signature");
    return (owner == signer);
}

function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address sender) {
    if (msg.sender == address(this)) {
        bytes memory array = msg.data;
        uint256 index = msg.data.length;
        assembly {
            // Load the 32 bytes word from memory with the address on the lower 20 bytes, and mask those.
            sender := and(
                mload(add(array, index)),
                0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
            )
        }
    } else {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
```

}